# TableView loading wrong cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Not really sure how to explain this but on my `UITableView` I have a line of code that when I click on a cell it takes me to a new view which updates it's title based on the name of the cell. However when if I have two cells, one named 'One' and one named 'Two', when I click 'Two' it takes me to a view with title 'One' and vice versa. Any idea's to what may be causing this? Sorry I can't be of more help.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    ACollection *newView = [[ACollection alloc] init];
    newView.theTitle = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: just show your code snippet... I guess its logical problem

Comment: please post the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code :)

Comment: accidentally using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` provides some interesting debugging experience. Code behaves totally strange, but looks correct. BTDTNT ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have chosen wrong method for this

Just try this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ACollection *newView = [[ACollection alloc] init];
    newView.theTitle = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have thank you! Just noticed the deselect instead of select, thank you